# Better tag for party compared to catering

Tags: discussion, tagging

In my question [Party scale sous-vide](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12744/party-scale-sous-vide) I wanted to convey the domestic side of cooking so I used tag `party-scale`, not the best tag in hind sight

But it got re-tagged catering, which is definitely not what it is about. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catering first line says "Catering is the business of providing food service ..."

Catering in any culture I know of means getting in professional help, not how you do things yourself for a large group

I thought the simple tag `party` would be OK, but apparently not. So what do you tag large scale domestic cooking?

Another idea `self-catering`

Comment: An [encyclopedia is not a dictonary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_dictionary#Overview:_encyclopedia_vs_dictionary). If you want to reference the definition of a word, you use a [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/catering).

Comment: @hobodave - Longman, a modern contemporary dictionary has catering as "the activity of providing and serving food and drinks at parties, meetings etc for money". Wiktionary the dictionary companion of Wikipedia has "The business of providing food and related services"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have the [bulk-cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulk-cooking) and [mass-cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-cooking) tags for this.

I'm not sure why we have two - the latter should probably be a synonym of the former.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better! `bulk-cooking` make sense to me

Answer (score 3):

The [catering](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catering) tag is meant for this. Catering is simply providing food for an event such as a wedding, party, funeral, or banquet. There is no restriction that limits catering to a professional or business capacity.

At this mature stage of our site our focus is more on consolidating and cleaning up existing tags. Creating new tags at this point in time is *generally* not necessary because it is unlikely we do not have an appropriate tag already. If you find yourself creating or "needing" a new tag you should carefully consider whether this is in fact needed, and not covered by an existing tag. In this case, [catering](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catering) covers the topic. Also, a tag with one question in it helps no one.

Thus, in the absence of a compelling argument that we need to differentiate between professional and non-professional catering, I don't think adding a new tag is warranted.

Comment: That is a very old English definition of catering, maybe a USA definition? Everyone else and contemporary English dictionaries define catering as "providing food for money". Another term more useful might be 'self-catering'

Comment: [Attempt at humour] It's a bit like the difference between making love to your wife and hiring a prostitute?

Comment: +1 In the US, catering as a verb means to provide food for a group of people at some type of event. It is not exclusive to businesses.